# google maps api v3 create markers in separate dom element

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, draggable

I have been able to create 2 markers and a tooltip that pertains to each marker with unique content. I would like the markers to NOT be draggable.

Changing draggable to false does not work. The tooltip stops appearing.

If I mess with the listeners, the marker becomes static, but the tooltip appears in the top left corner of the map.

I'm new to javascript as well as google maps... working on a final project and your help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my script:

```
var map ;


function initialize() {






function Tooltip(opts, marker) {
    // Initialization
    this.setValues(opts);
    this.map_ = opts.map;
    this.marker_ = marker;
    var div = this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
    // Class name of div element to style it via CSS
    div.className = "tooltip";
    this.markerDragging = false;
}
Tooltip.prototype = {
// Define draw method to keep OverlayView happy
    draw: function() {},
        visible_changed: function() {
            var vis = this.get("visible");
            this.div_.style.visibility = vis ? "visible" : "hidden";
        },
    getPos: function(e) {
        var projection = this.getProjection();
        // Position of mouse cursor
        var pixel = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(e.latLng);
        var div = this.div_;
        // Adjust the tooltip's position
        var gap = 15;
        var posX = pixel.x + gap;
        var posY = pixel.y + gap;
        var menuwidth = div.offsetWidth;
        // Right boundary of the map
        var boundsNE = this.map_.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        boundsNE.pixel = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(boundsNE);
            if (menuwidth + posX > boundsNE.pixel.x) {
                posX -= menuwidth + gap;
            }
        div.style.left = posX + "px";
        div.style.top = posY + "px";
        if (!this.markerDragging) {
            this.set("visible", true);
        }
    },
    addTip: function() {
        var me = this;
        var div = me.div_;
        div.innerHTML = me.get("text").toString();
        // Tooltip is initially hidden
        me.set("visible", false);
        // Append the tooltip's div to the floatPane
        me.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(this.div_);
        // In IE this listener gets randomly lost after it's been cleared once.
        // So keep it out of the listeners array.
            google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, "dragend", function() {
                me.markerDragging = false; 
            });
        // Register listeners
        me.listeners = [
        // g.addListener(me.marker_, "dragend", function() {
        // me.markerDragging = false; }),
            google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, "position_changed", function() {
                me.markerDragging = true;
                me.set("visible", false); 
            }),
            google.maps.event.addListener(me.map_, "mousemove", function(e) {
                me.getPos(e); 
            })
        ];
    },
    removeTip: function() {
    // Clear the listeners to stop events when not needed.
        if (this.listeners) {
            for (var i = 0, listener; listener = this.listeners[i]; i++) {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
        }
        delete this.listeners;
    }
// Remove the tooltip from the map pane.
    var parent = this.div_.parentNode;
    if (parent) parent.removeChild(this.div_);
}
};

function inherit(addTo, getFrom) {
    var from = getFrom.prototype; // prototype object to get methods from
    var to = addTo.prototype; // prototype object to add methods to
        for (var prop in from) {
            if (typeof to[prop] == "undefined") to[prop] = from[prop];
        }
}
// Inherits from OverlayView from the Google Maps API
inherit(Tooltip, google.maps.OverlayView);
function createMarker(point, name) {
    var image = { url: 'styles/styleImgs/marker_food.png'};
/** Set both draggable and optimized marker properties to false
* when using non draggable markers.
* Tooltip needs markers rendered in separate DOM elements.
*/
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    icon: image,
    tooltip: name
});
var tooltip = new Tooltip({map: map}, marker);
tooltip.bindTo("text", marker, "tooltip");
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
        // Add the tooltip not before hovering over a marker
        tooltip.addTip();
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
        // Remove the tooltip on every mouseout
        tooltip.removeTip();
    });
return marker;
}


var styles = [
              {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#ffffff" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  { "weight": 2.8 },
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#ffffff" },
                  { "saturation": 17 }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  { "color": "#caddd8" },
                  { "visibility": "on" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#caddd8" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "administrative.province",
                "elementType": "labels.text",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#00667c" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "administrative.country",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#00667c" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  { "color": "#00667c" },
                  { "visibility": "on" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "landscape",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  { "color": "#00667c" },
                  { "visibility": "on" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "landscape",
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#caddd8" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "administrative.province",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#d1d2d4" },
                  { "weight": 0.3 }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "transit",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "administrative.country",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "weight": 0.6 },
                  { "color": "#ffffff" }
                ]
              },{
              }
            ] ;

function buildMap() {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, -102);
    var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.07, -89.5);

    var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(10 , 0),
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoom: 3,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
              style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
            },
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
            }
    };  

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: "Styled Map"});



  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

    var marker = createMarker(point, "<b>First****</b><br />This is the first draggable testmarker");
    var marker2 = createMarker(point2, "<b>Second***</b><br />This is the second draggable testmarker");
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAeyZfOHXuoEZ926ckF1GXn7MkotVpCPio&sensor=false";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = buildMap();
window.onload = loadScript;


} //end initialize
```